# Trying to find the /etc/resolve

Tags: macos, network, dns

I'm trying to connect a Macbook Air running 10.8.4 to a Windows 2008 R2 server. I have run into trouble as we use a `company.local`. 
I think this may be the problem: http://blog.scottlowe.org/2006/01/04/mac-os-x-and-local-domains/.

So, I have gone into terminal and typed `open /private` and navigated to the `etc` folder but can not find a resolve folder, only a `resolv.conf` file.

How do I go about adding the name server?

Answer (score 2):

That is a 7 year old link!  Try just opening the resolv.conf file which is a text file that contains a list of DNS servers.  It may be blank, in which case you can just add lines using the following format as an example:

```
nameserver 172.16.1.254
nameserver 172.16.2.254
```

Check [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolv.conf) for a bit more

Comment: This won't work, as OS X doesn't actually use /etc/resolv.conf.

Answer (score 1):

The way OS X handles .local domains changes frequently between versions of, and as @stuffe said, that's a very old link so its advice is pretty much irrelevant now. For 10.8.4, Apple recommends [adding the .local domain to the DNS Search Domains list in Network preferences](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5738).

(For versions OS X 10.6 and 10.7, see [KB article #TS4041](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS4041) instead.)